# HOMFLY polynomial is invariant under Reidemeister moves

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Is there an easy way to verify that the HOMFLY polynomial is invariant under Reidemeister moves?

For Jones polynomial, it is obvious by the way it is defined (not via skein relations). It is proved in the book by Colin Adams.

There is no proof for HOMFLY polynomial in the book and the original paper by the mathematicians HOMFLY.

Comment: Chapter 15 of Lickorish's book "An Introduction to Knot Theory" elaborates on the "Lickorish and Millett approach" from the original HOMFLY paper.  There are also some state-sum models like Murakami-Ohtsuki-Yamada (commonly MOY).

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for in the book you mentioned. I like Lickorish's book, it is more precise in its language compared to Adams' book.